# Preserve selection between tableviews

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have 2 tableviews in 2 xibs with both their own class. What I want to achieve is that when TableView1's selected row is 4 that TableView2's selected row is also 4 and the other way around. So the selected row number should be the same between the TableViews. How do I achieve this?

I was thinking something like: tableview1.tablerow == tableview2.tablerow, but no idea how to execute this.

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved in many ways. Creating a property on both table views and set it to the selected cell for example:

On both tableViews

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *selectedCell;
```

On the selection of one cell just set the parameter on the other

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   //imagine there is a reference to the tableView2
   self.tableView2.selectedCell = indexPath;
   //display the tableView2 or do whatever is needed
}
```

and on viewWillAppear of tableView2 just set the selected row to reflect that property

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{  
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];    
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCell animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone]; 
}
```

And the same the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is what I was looking for but im running into something tho. The tableviews are pop ups displayed when clicking on a button. When I select a row in tableview1 the row in tableview2 updates. But when I click on tableview1 again the row is still the same row as the previous row in tableview2. I hope you understand the issue!

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you elaborate more the example? Anyway is just saving at some place the selected indexPath and updating the other table when needed (viewWillAppear or whatever fits your needs)

Comment: Well when I select a row at TableView1 the row updates to TableView2, as expected. But when I click on TableView 1 again the selected row is the row previously selected in TableView2. Not really sure how to explain it properly.

Comment: I thought that that was exactly what you where looking for, that both tables have always the same cell selected, so if you select something on tb1 the same cell is selected on tb2 and if you select some cell on tb2 the same one is selected on tb1. Not sure if I am getting it :)

Comment: Well yeah, both tables should always have the same cell selected. But that is currently not the case. Whats happening is that tb1 holds the selection of tb2, and tb2 holds the selection of tb1. So they both have a different selection.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a receiver in the tableviewcontroller for TableView2 and when you select a row in TableView1 update TableView2 with something like this:

```
NSManagedObjectID* selectedRow=[[self.frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] objectID];
TableView2* tableview2controller=[[TableView2 alloc] init];
tableview2controller.selectedRow = selectedRow;
```

Comment: I'd have to add that im a beginner at this, I understand the solution but I don't know how to write the code exactly.

Comment: Ah... Emilio just posted a more detailed solution above, so go with that.